# Docker Compose 'hot-reload' Issue

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

While I've seen the other questions -- none of the proposed solutions or documentation has helped me thus far. Apologies if this is somewhat redundant.

I'm trying to mount a volume in my `docker-compose.yml` file in order to 'hot-reload' my code as I make changes. I'm running a flask app. My file structure looks as follows:

```
├── celery_queue
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── tasks.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── my_test_app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_test_app.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── worker.py
├── run.sh
└── stop.sh
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web:
    build:
      context: ./my_test_app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./my_test_app:/my_test_app
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  worker:
    build:
      context: celery_queue
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - redis
  monitor:
    build:
      context: celery_queue
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "5555:5555"
    entrypoint: flower
    command:  -A tasks --port=5555 --broker=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

And finally -- the `Dockerfile` in the `my_test_app` dir:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV CELERY_BROKER_URL redis://redis:6379/0
ENV CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND redis://redis:6379/0
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV PORT 5000
ENV DEBUG true

ADD . /my_test_app
WORKDIR /my_test_app

# install requirements
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

# expose the app port
EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install gunicorn

# run the app server
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "--workers", "3", "my_test_app:app"]
```

Again -- my goal is to edit the Flask code in the `my_test_app` directory and have it reload in my container without starting/stopping.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was actually related to my Gunicorn command, which requires a `--reload` flag.

Steps I used to solve the issue:

1) Since I'm using OSX, I confirmed in my Docker preferences that file-sharing was enabled for this dir.

2) I exec'd into the container to check if the files were updating upon code chagnes:
`docker exec -it my-container-name sh`

3) They were updating as expected, so I checked the gunicorn/flask documentation.

Comment: so actually CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "--workers", "3", "my_test_app:app" "--reload"] is needed . correct ?